# How to make requests to an endpoint with 'core-ui' template

Tags: reactjs, core-ui

I am a beginner with React. I discovered this template "core-ui" which is very popular :

https://github.com/coreui/coreui-free-react-admin-template

I installed it in my local machine. And is works, perfect. Very beautiful, I will use it.

Now I would like to make requests to some external endpoints and retrieve some data (for a table, for a login , etc....). I did not find how to do that in the documentation. I searched in the code where and how to do that, without success.

How can I do that?

Comment: You'd do it the same way as in any other `React` project. This template only provides you with a set of reusable components that you can use to build your dashboard, other business logic needs to be implemented by you. Have a look here https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html or https://blog.bitsrc.io/making-api-calls-with-react-hooks-748ebfc7de8c

Comment: Thanks goto1. It s not really a framework but a template. I will implement the fetches myself.